# How to change storybook base URL

Tags: javascript, svelte, storybook, storybook-addon-specifications, storybook-addon

does anyone know how to set up a different base URL for storybook? when you run "npm run storybook" it opens up on **http://localhost:6006/**, how can i get it to open up on **http://localhost:6006/storybook/**?

Answer (score 0):

Long story short, it's not compatible with the ports' convention(s).
The ports that host the running of your application(s) are reserved for one app at a time, and they take the route(s) from application's router rather than opening it up on a custom base like **http://localhost:6006/storybook/?**.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Vite.js, you can set `base: '/storybook/',` in the `viteFinal` function of the `.storybook/main.{js|ts}` file

Answer (score 0):

This doesn't work as storybook use express.js for the dev server. See the issue here: [github issue](https://github.com/storybookjs/storybook/discussions/25858)
Something like this should be added here [github link](https://github.com/storybookjs/storybook/blob/next/code/lib/core-server/src/dev-server.ts), but probably not possible now ...

```js
app.use('/baseUrl', router);
```